# What is the POSIX shell equivalent of bash <<<

Tags: bash, sh

I have a variable that looks sort of like this:

```
msg="newton apple tree"
```

I want to assign each of these words into separate variables.  This is easy to do in bash:

```
read a b c <<< $msg
```

Is there a compact, readable way to do this in POSIX shell?

Comment: 'bash' stands for 'Bourne Again Shell'. It's a bigger, better, faster version of 'Bourne Shell'. So it's unlikely.

Comment: I don't know how *readable* you'd consider it, but it amounts to using a pipe.  Is that a possibility you've already rejected?

Comment: If there existed a POSIX sh (you probably don't really mean Bourne -- Bourne is a shell from the 70s; unless you're on moderately-oldish Solaris, nobody has Bourne) equivalent, why would bash have had to introduce the feature?

Comment: Not rejecting anything.  Any reasonable solution will do.  I thought I could eval 'echo $msg | read a b c', but that doesn't appear to work.  Perhaps you have a working solution?

Comment: Right -- that doesn't work, because the pipeline creates a subshell, and the variables' values are scoped to it.

Comment: If you're going to use them immediately, you can `echo "$msg" | { read a b c; do_something_with "$a"; }`, but the values are still unset when the pipeline is shut down.

Comment: That is a nice way Charles, but unfortunately I need to re-use them.  I have to leave bash and go into the world of busybox.

Comment: BTW, you might find http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 to be of interest -- it covers behavior of pure POSIX, ksh, etc. as well as bash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To write idiomatic scripts, you can't just look at each individual syntax element and try to find a POSIX equivalent. That's like translating text by replacing each individual word with its entry in the dictionary.

The POSIX way of splitting a string known to have three words into three arguments, similar but not identical to `read` is:

```
var="newton apple tree"

set -f
set -- $var
set +f
a=$1 b=$2 c=$3

echo "$a was hit by an $b under a $c"
```

Comment: I might do that work in a function to avoid overwriting the global `$@`, but this is a great solution.

Comment: This unnecessarily overwrites the positional parameters; a here string is just a shortcut for single-line here documents, so there is no need to replace the `read` with the `set` command.

Answer (score 31):

A here string is just syntactic sugar for a single-line here document:

```
$ msg="foo * bar"
$ read a b c <<EOF
> $msg
> EOF
$ echo "$a"
foo
$ echo "$b"
*
$ echo "$c"
bar
```

Comment: What if a variable has new line characters?

Comment: Then the command can read multiple lines. By "single-line", I just mean that whatever you supply as the here string will correspond to a here document with one line of code.

Comment: I have a variable that contains text - one sentence on each line. When I try your example, it can only read the first line, i.e. only `echo "$a"` shows the output. Other lines get omitted. For example, `echo "$b"` is empty.

Comment: The *string* consists of multiple lines, but `read` only reads one of them. If you want to read three lines from the here-string, you need three separate `read` commands, like `{ read a; read b; read c; } <<< "$FOO"`.

Comment: Thanks, is there a chance to get this solution in POSIX?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/26849247/1126841.

Comment: Ha, right. I just don't get it how to convert this to POSIX since `{ read a; read b }` is bashism.

Comment: That's not a bashism; it's supported by POSIX.

Comment: Very helpful. If you don't mind, I'll add this answer to this thread.

Comment: Readling two lines from standard input has nothing to do with the question as asked.

Comment: @t7e if the variable has newlines in it, the OP version with the here-string will also only read up to the first newline.  OP asked for an equivalent, which this is, not a way to handle multi-ilne values.

Answer (score 6):

It's not pretty, but as a general-purpose solution, you can work around this with a named pipe.

From [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024):

```
mkfifo mypipe
printf '%s\n' "$msg" >mypipe &
read -r a b c <mypipe
```

`printf` is more reliable / better-specified than `echo`; echo behavior varies between implementations if you have a message containing only, say, `-E` or `-n`.

---

That said, for what you're doing here, you could just use parameter expansion:

```
a=${msg%% *}; msg=${msg#* }
b=${msg%% *}; msg=${msg#* }
c=${msg%% *}; msg=${msg#* }
```

Comment: I think you need to add 'a b c' instead of line to make it more relevant to my example.  But, this looks like a possible answer.

Comment: ah, okay that looks better.

Comment: I'd like to give you the check to, but I think that guy has a more elegant solution.  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Bitdiot, it's absolutely a more elegant solution; he has my upvote for it. I'm leaving this one in place only because it works in cases where the other isn't as appropriate (such as processing multiple lines).